# setup.py not packaging application

Tags: python, python-3.x, setuptools

Windows 10

Python 3.10.4

I have a very basic python package linked here for reference: https://github.com/Edouard87/example-python-package.

The structure is this:

```
example_package/
|-- setup.py
ˋ-- src/
    ˋ-- example_pkg/
        |-- __init__.py
        |-- module1.py
```

My `setup.py` looks like this:

```py
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name        = "example_package",
    package_dir = {"example_pkg": "src"},
    packages    = ["example_pkg"]
)
```

`module1.py` looks like this:

```py
def func_1():
    print("imported")

def cli():
    print("ran cli.")

class TestClass:
    def test_method(self):
        print("test!")
```

`__init__.py` is empty.

I want to be able to import `example_pkg` into the python interpreter. Because I don't want to have permissions issues with my global python interpreter, I'm using a `venv` and I made sure to activate it.

I run `pip install -e .`. Then I run `pip list` which gives me:

```
example-package 0.0.0   c:\users\me\documents\python\example_package\.venv\lib\site-packages
pip             22.0.4
```

Now, I launch `python` and in the REPL I run:

```py
import example_pkg
```

This gives me a `ModuleImportError`. I looked into `lib/site-packages` and the `.egg-link`s are there and are pointing to the correct directories.

I don't understand why this isn't working. Can anyone point to something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Fix:

```
package_dir = {'': 'src'}
```

See https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#listing-whole-packages :

"*The keys to this dictionary are package names, and **an empty package name stands for the root package**.*" — emphasize mine (*phd*).